# An Elliptical Cropping of an Image

Tags: tikz-pgf, includegraphics, grids, crop-image, ellipse

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}

\begin{document}%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\begin{overpic}[scale=0.4,unit=2mm,grid,tics=2]{example-image-a}
\end{overpic}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following image and grid:

[image]

I would like to crop the A-image in the shape of an ellipse by specifying the center and foci.

QUESTION: How may I specify, say center=(14,9) and foci=(14,4) and (14,14), in order to crop the image in the shape of the ellipse produced?

Remark: I'm not sure this will produce the most desirable ellipse for the job, but knowing how to do this, the numbers can then be tweaked.

Thank you.

Comment: Combine it with `tikz` and use `tikz`'s tools to clip to a certain shape.

Comment: You just need to compute the radii of your desired ellipse and then clip your image inside of it with Ti*k*Z.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that center and foci isn't sufficient to define the ellipse.  But it seems like you're not committed to using those, and just need some way to define the ellipse.

Comment: @Teepeemm Well, as an ellipse is the collection of all points in the plane, the sum of whose distances from two fixed points (foci) is a constant, I figured specifying the center and foci would be sufficient. However, now that I think of it, being given just the foci, ought to be sufficient to imply the center.

Comment: But you also need to specify that constant distance.

Comment: @Teepeemm Ah! That's right. Thank you.

Comment: Many ways to define an ellipse, knowing some of its lengths, indeed. But defining it with its minor and major axes is the most natural way with Ti*k*Z.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A very rough solution to start with. Using `clip` and including the picture in a node. Just adapt the lengths of axes.

[image: elliptical cropping]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \clip (0,0) ellipse (8cm and 5cm);
            \node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[scale=2]{example-image-a}};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer.